# PHP, new variable class in namespace

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I'm experimenting with PHP 5.3's namespacing functionality and I just can't figure out how to instantiate a new class with namespace prefixing.

This currently works fine:

```
<?php
new $className($args);
?>
```

But how I can prepend my namespace in front of a variable classname? The following example doesn't work.

```
<?php
new My\Namespace\$className($args);
?>
```

This example yields: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE**

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
$class = "My\Namespace\\$className";
new $class();
```

There must be two backslashes `\\` before the variable `$className` to escape it

Comment: wont u need to escape the back slash?  "My\\Namespace\\$className";

Comment: I don't get it... why is this necessary? I had to do the same thing. Is it something wrong with the PHP install?

Comment: The reason for the double backslash is that the backslash is a functional character and needs to be escaped itself.

Comment: Someone please explain this. Why the hell it's not possible to instantiate a namespaced class without using strings :| weird.

Comment: @Stichoza it is possible, but in the question asked OP is mixing a namespace with a string which makes no sense, why would php expect a random string dropped into the middle of the line. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php

Comment: Yes the backslash before `$className` must be escaped

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
$classPath = sprintf('My\Namespace\%s', $className);
$class = new $classPath;
```

Note the single quotes instead of double.