# Create new class instance from string name in an aliased namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I've seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921911/instantiate-a-new-class-from-a-variables-name-in-a-namespace) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936519/php-new-variable-class-in-namespace), but neither addresses how to create a class instance from a string name if you already have a namespace and the class is in an aliased namespace:

```
<?php
namespace my\project;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Example aliased classes, more may be defined elsewhere
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;
use Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft;

//This is mapped from a submitted form value
$provider = 'Google';

$g = new $provider;
```

This throws `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google' not found`. In those questions, it says you should prefix with `__NAMESPACE__`, but the problem is that these classes are not in the `my\project` namespace so that doesn't work either, because it results in a class name of `my\project\Google` which doesn't exist.

A dumb fix for this specific code would be to use an array to store all the namespaces and class names, but that can't work if I don't know all possible class names in advance.

I can't even see how to use reflection to solve this because I can't create a reflection object for the aliased class for the same reason - `new \ReflectionClass($provider);` throws the same error.

How can I get the namespace of an aliased class name dynamically?

Comment: Try `use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google as Google`

Comment: @Xorifelse, nope, that's the same as what I have

Answer (score 1):

You will simply have to use:

```
$provider = 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google';
```

There is no other solution, class name variables need to contain the fully qualified class name; aliasing doesn't apply to string class names, and introspection can't help you either.

Comment: Yes, this is clear. But if the class file is loaded, OP can (try to) retrieve his complete name. +1 for your clarity/concision

Comment: And the "(try to)" is exactly the reason that approach is rather... suboptimal. :) Explicitly name the class by its full(ly qualified) name, period.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are introduced to allow same names in different contexts, so the answer is: no, it is not possible.

You can have a class `\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google` and another class `\League\OAuth1\Client\Provider\Google`: in this case, how you can determine what class to instantiate?

Assuming you know that there are only unique class names, you can use this code:

```
$provider = 'Google';
$found = False;
foreach( get_declared_classes() as $class )
{
    if( preg_match( "~(.*\\\)?($provider)$~", $class ) )
    {
        $found = $class;
        break;
    }
}

if( $found )
{
    $g = new '\\'.$found;
}
else
{
    echo "No '$provider' class found";
}
```

<kbd>**[demo with DateTime class](https://eval.in/548073)**</kbd>

but this routine is only a simplification of your idea “to use an array to store all the namespaces and class names”, because — even with above code — if you don't know all declared classes, you can obtain unwanted results.

Comment: Thanks. There are further twists to this - autoloaded classes won't be in the `get_declared_classes` list yet, and having a `use` statement does not necessarily imply that a class exists - that only matters when you try to instantiate it.

Comment: If you use autoload I think you don't have chances: how can php know what do you want?

Comment: It does know what I want! If I use the aliased class name explicitly, `$a = new Google;`, it works fine. I think this is possibly a PHP bug - class name resolution seems to be not quite in the right order.

Comment: autoload is stock composer.

Comment: do you call `require something/vendor/autoload.php; require something/vendor/autoload.php; ect...` ?

Comment: No. I get the feeling you don't use composer. This isn't a class loading problem.

Comment: Your solution is inside your autoloader

Comment: It's really not. I can cause the same issue without using an autoloader at all; the problem appears before any autoloader code is run, and static naming works perfectly. It's the naming that's the problem, not the loading.

Comment: You are lost in a classic XY problem: your assumption fails, so you are fixed to it. But yes, your real problem is the class loading (this is your goal). When a class il loaded, you know how find its complete name, so you have to concentrate to it.